# Area is not passed to Url.Action() in ASP.net Core

Tags: asp.net-core-mvc, asp.net-core-2.0

The following code is working in normal ASP.net MVC.

```
Url.Action("actionName", "controllerName", new { Area = "areaName" });
```

But it is not work well in ASP.net Core. Area is recognized as a query string parameter.

How can I solve it?
Thanks for any help.

Comment: Area is new feature in ASP.NET Core so you to configure it in Startup class.

Comment: I did it already and even I added [Area("areaName")] at the first of my controller. But it does not work on Url.Action().

Comment: Have you tried with taghelper syntax?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Make sure you're registering routes as below :

```
app.UseMvc(routes =>
{
    routes.MapRoute(
        name: "areaRoute",
        // if you don't have such an area named as `areaName` already, 
        //    don't make the part of `{area}` optional by `{area:exists}`
        template: "{area}/{controller=Home}/{action=Index}");  

    routes.MapRoute(
        name: "default",
        template: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
});
```

I could reproduce the same issue as yours by changing the order of routes, or by changing the `{area}` to be optional.

1. **The Order matters**. The `areaRoute` should come first. Don't change the order.
2. When generating url to an area, **if you don't have such an area already, don't change the part of `{area}` to be optional** by  `{area:exists}`. For example, let's say you're trying to generate a url to area of `MyAreaName`:

   ```
   Url.Action("actionName", "controllerName", new { Area = "MyAreaName" });
   ```

   If there's no area named as `MyAreaName` in your project, and you've made the area `optional` by:

   ```
   routes.MapRoute(
       name: "areaRoute",
       template: "{area:exists}/{controller=Home}/{action=Index}");
   ```

   the generated url will be `controllerName/actionName?Area=MyAreaName`.